# Verificação de HTTP(200) em PHP

Tags: php, http-request

Eu fiz minha verificação assim, só que no meu deu um erro e em outros sistemas de verificação não deu. Gostaria de saber aonde foi que eu errei?

```
 $host = 'IP do HOST';
 $conectado = @fsockopen($host, 80);

 if (is_resource($conectado)) {
    print 'online';
 }else{
    print 'offline';
 }
```

Abaixo meu sistema e outro sistema verificado.

[image: Meu sistema]

[image: Sistema verificado]

Comment: Você está utilizando `curl_init` ? Ou você saber se sua página está retornando o status 200?

Comment: Pois é eu tentei fazer via CURL mais minha hospedagem de teste não permite eu acho.

Comment: Eu quero enviar um comando para uma pagina para me retornar o valor 200.

Comment: Utilize [**curl_getinfo**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.curl-getinfo.php)

Comment: Não aparece nem curl_getinfo(); como tbm não aparece phpinfo();

Comment: da o erro 404 na pagina.

Comment: Já tentou verificar a resposta com o [**stream_get_meta_data**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.stream-get-meta-data.php) ?

Comment: Como faço isso?

Comment: Se possível [edit] sua pergunta e adicione como você está fazendo. Fica mais fácil mostrar uma solução.

Comment: Pronto alterei, tentei ser o mais claro possível.

Comment: No meu sistema so voltou as 14:40 no outro sistema de verificação nem caiu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para utilizar o `fsockopen`, você precisa remover o *schema* (`http://`) e a barra no final.

Exemplo:

```
$host = 'pt.stackoverflow.com';
$conectado = fsockopen($host, 80);

if (is_resource($conectado)) {
    print 'online';
}else{
    print 'offline';
}
```

---

#### Alternativas

Além do `fsockpopen`, você também pode utilizar `fopen` e `curl`.

**Exemplo com `fopen`:**

```
$host = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com/';
$conectado = fopen($host, 'r');

@$result = @stream_get_meta_data($conectado);

if (is_resource($conectado) && strpos($result['wrapper_data'][0], "200") !== false) {
    print 'online';
}else{
    print 'offline';
}
```

**Exemplo com `curl`:**

```
$host = 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com:80';

ob_start();
$ch = curl_init($host);
curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
ob_end_clean();

if( $info === 200 ) {
    echo "Offline";
} else {
    echo "Offline";
}
```

Comment: Eu errei, vou alterar na pergunta. Pq no meu sistema não tem "/". E com fopen e curl não funciona no meu sistema de testes.

Comment: Consegui, eu estava errando mesmo numa coisa no meu código o seu me fez ver. Obrigado a todos, pela ajuda